# Why I can't get the map entry in hazelcast mancenter console?

Tags: java, hazelcast

I'm running simple java class with this code in main:

```
Map<Integer, String> customers = hazelcastInstance.getMap( "customers" );
customers.put( 1, "test" );
```

If I run hazelcast mancenter, I will be able to get entries list in console:

```
> ns cusomters
customers> m.entries
1: test
```

But if I try to get some value by id, I always get null:

```
customers> m.get 1
null
```

And if I put some entries in console, I will be able to get them:

```
customers> m.put 5 test2
null
customers> m.get 5
5 : test2
```

What am I doing wrong? Please help.

Comment: could you please post the code of 'getting some value by id' as you mentioned?

Comment: I'm trying to do it in console: 
m.get 5

Comment: Have you checked the same scenario on Map Browser as mentioned in docs http://docs.hazelcast.org/docs/latest/manual/html/managementcenter.html#maps.

Comment: Yes, it's working for entries I put with my java class.

Comment: Seems like the 'key type' of the id you are entering in console is not Integer as the 'key type' of your Map<Integer, String> is Integer. That's why you are getting null.

Comment: How can I enter it right? There is no information about using keys in console in the docs.

Comment: I am not sure whether the issue is with key type. That's why i said you to check the scenario in Map Browser.In Map browser you can define the key type of the id.If it is working fine over there then the issue is with key type in console.

Comment: Map Browser is working ok even if I use String as a key in the map:
Map<String, String> customers...

Comment: See, you have a Map<Integer, String> customers .Now the key type is Integer. Now do one thing in your Map browser,select the key type 'String'  and then click on the browse button. After doing this tell me are you getting null value?

Comment: Vikas, Map Browser is ok. If I use Map<Integer, String>, I'm able to get value by Integer key in the Browser. If I use Map<String, String>, I'm able to get it by String key.

Comment: Ok, if I use Map<String, String> in my code, I can get value in console: 
customers> m.get 1
1 : test
Vicas, you were right. In console key in the m.get method is String.

Comment: But how can I get it by Integer key in console? :-)

Comment: Try one more thing , use IMap<Integer, String> customers instead of Map<Integer, String> customers . Not sure if this works.

Comment: It works the same way :((

Comment: Then i don't know buddy. I checked all the commands of hazelcast mancenter console and i am unable to find anything related to your issue.May be this is a bug.

Comment: Thanks anyway. Now I know where the problem is.

Comment: so what was the issue?

Comment: Well, with the types. I don't solve it yet :-)

Comment: OK.Please post the answer when you get it resolved.

Comment: Of course. Thank you.

Comment: I think I found the answer:
"You should not use the console. It is just a toy without any real value. Imho we should remove it from the core." :-)

Comment: Hey Andrey, you are right m.get on console is processing input as string. You can see the details here: https://github.com/hazelcast/hazelcast/blob/master/hazelcast/src/main/java/com/hazelcast/console/ConsoleApp.java#L726

Comment: Thank you, Murat. It's all clear now.

Comment: Hi @Andrey, did you manage to get value for integer keys using management center?

Answer (score 0):

I would not use the mancenter for this. Just rely on regular java to access the IMap.